# EOSIO Tutorial: Development Public Key vs eosio development key

Tags: cleos, tutorial

Many questions, thanks in advance for any help.

In the eosio tutorial ([1.4 Create dev wallet](https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.0/getting-started/development-environment/create-development-wallet)) I have created a wallet and the message returned is:

`Created new private key with a public key of: "EOS7yPf8nD...`

This is called the "development public key" by the step #4 & #5 in the docs.
Step #6 introduces the eosio development key, and then we issue the command:

```
cleos wallet import
```

and it asks for the "eosio development key", which is "5KQwrPb...". The definition of this command is: **Imports private key into wallet**

Question #1: Have I imported the private key of: "EOS7yPf8nD..." into wallet?

Question #2: Is the eosio dev key used to allow us to import keys into wallet?

Question #3: How do I verify or even identify these keys? (aka Is it for "default"?)

Moving to [1.6 Create Test Accounts](https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.0/getting-started/development-environment/create-test-accounts) we now create accounts. We issue the command:

```
cleos create account eosio bob EOS7yPf8nD...
```

We place "bob" in the "default wallet", using the wallet key "EOS7yPf8nD..."

Last question: Did I do this correct? I have the account and the wallet with the same keys! That does not feel correct to me. I got lost somewhere?

Comment: There is a telegram for EOSIO development where you can ask questions as well: https://t.me/joinchat/DQRZHEPktgcLlyfbl-bDuQ

Comment: Its a long question, I don't think it goes well on Telegram. Maybe I will try  and post an answer back here if I get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wallet itself comes with its own secret key when it generates the wallet keys.

```
Creating wallet: default
Save password to use in the future to unlock this wallet.
Without password imported keys will not be retrievable.
"PW5...<redacted>"
```

This key will be used to unlock your wallet to import additional keys into your wallet. You may use this secret key to check which private keys are imported in your wallet by performing the following:

```
cleos wallet private_keys
```

Inside you will see an array of arrays. The first element in the array is the public key. While the second is the private. All corresponding Public Keys generally begin with **EOS**.

You may also view all public keys by performing.

```
cleos wallet keys
```

Anyway, the first Public Key you generated should be used for your development purposes and should be the one you submit into the documentation so the rest of your documentation syncs up.

Hope this answers some if not all of your questions.

Comment: Thanks for info. It took a few reads and my own tinkering to get the hang of this. I think my prior definition of wallet and the definition or purpose of the wallet here threw me.